# Receive any iterable container

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Is there any way to receive any iterable container as a parameter?

I would like a function to be able to receive any container while being able to `begin()` and `end()` on it. Unless I am wrong, every container should have these functions (`std::view` does not?).

Specifically, is there a way to receive a [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) as an argument?

C++20 and/or tempates are fine.

```cpp
void do_stuff(any_iterable_collection<int> &coll) {
    for (auto it = coll.begin() ; it != coll.end() ; ++it) {
        // do stuff with *it
    }
}

std::list<int>   list;
std::vector<int> vector;
std::set<int>    set;

do_stuff(list);
do_stuff(vector);
do_stuff(set);
```

Comment: Well, you can just receive a `typename T` as a template parameter, and take it on faith that it's a container that implements `begin()`, `end()`, and other things that a template does. If you're asking to restrict the template parameter to something that only supports these operations, this is fairly easy to do, and the best approach depends on which C++ revision level you need to use. C++20 introduced a completely different way to do that. In either case you need to define in concrete details what "container" means to you, in terms of supported methods.

Comment: Is there a reason not to have the function take a pair of iterators, as most standard library algorithms do in a similar situation?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wanted to be able to use it like do_stuff(std::vector{1, 2, 3}) too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the same way the standard perform this action:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void do_stuff(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    for (auto it = first; it != last; it = std::next(it)) {
        // do stuff with *it
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 5, 9};
    do_stuff(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you insist on the container:

```
template <template<typename> class Container>
void do_stuff(Container<int> &container) {
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); it = std::next(it)) {
        // do stuff with *it
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or for more generally container:

```
template <template<typename> class Container, typename CType>
void do_stuff(Container<CType> &container) {
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); it = std::next(it)) {
        // do stuff with *it
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: my thought exactly - just pass an iterator

Comment: If you really want to pass in a single container parameter that supports iteration, you should use [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)/[`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) instead, or even the [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) concept introduced in the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) of C++20.

Comment: I wouldn't use a template template for the container. Your code would (for example) not accept an `std::array` since that always needs two template parameters (type and size).

Comment: @RemyLebeau `std::ranges::range` does exactly what I wanted, thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, I fixed my answer. You renewed to me about the `concept` in `C++20`, I will definitely look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @n314159 You are definitely right. One more reason not to use it- it is way more complicated to archive the target than it can be (for example, as showed in the first option of sending iterators).

Answer (score 4):

A simplified [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) concept based on your requirements:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename C, typename T>
concept any_iterable_collection = 
    std::same_as<typename C::value_type, T> &&
    requires (C c) {
        { c.begin() } -> std::forward_iterator;
        { c.end() }   -> std::forward_iterator;
        { const_cast<const C&>(c).begin() } -> std::forward_iterator;
        { const_cast<const C&>(c).end() }   -> std::forward_iterator;
    };
```

Usage:

```
void do_stuff(const any_iterable_collection<int> auto& coll);
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SuVNboHPaEoANgE8)

Comment: I got that working with `void do_stuff(const any_iterable_collection<int> auto& coll);` like in your demo. `auto collection<int> const&` did not work because of `wrong number of template arguments`. It does exactly what I expected thanks!